# How do I figure out why a large chunk of memory is not being garbage collected in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm pretty new to Ruby, Rails, and everything else in that ecosystem. I've joined a team that has a Ruby 3.1.2 / Rails 6.1.7 app backed by a Postgres database.

We have a scenario where, sometimes, memory usage on one of our running instances jumps up significantly and is never relinquished (we've waited days). Until today, we didn't know what was causing it or how to reproduce it.

It turns out that it's caused by an internal tool which was running an unbounded ActiveRecord query -- no limit and no paging. When pointing this tool at a more active customer, it takes many seconds, returns thousands of records, and memory usage increases by tens of MB. No amount of waiting will lead to the memory usage going back down again.

Having discovered that, we recently added paging to that particular tool, and in the ~week since, we have not seen usage increasing in giant chunks anymore. However, there are other scenarios which have similar behavior but with smaller payloads; these cause memory usage to increase gradually over time. We deploy this application often enough that it hasn't been a big deal, but I am looking to gain a better understanding of what's happening and to determine if there's a problem here, because that's not what we should see from a stable application that's free of memory leaks.

My first suspicion was a memoized instance variable on the controller, but a quick check indicates that Rails controllers are discarded as soon as the request finishes processing, so I don't think that's it.

My next suspicion was that ActiveRecord was caching my resultset, but I've done a bunch of research on how this works and my understanding is that any cached queries/relations should be released when the request completes. Even if I have that wrong, a subsequent identical request takes just as long and causes another jump in memory usage, so either that's not it, or caching is broken on our system.

My Google searches turn up lots of results about various caching capabilities in Rails 2, 3, and 5 -- but not much about 6.x, so maybe something significant has changed and I just haven't found it.

I did find ruby-prof, memory-profiler, and get_process_mem -- these all seem like they are only suitable for high-level analysis and wouldn't help me here.

Can I explore the contents of the object graph currently in memory on an existing, live instance of my app? I'm imagining that this would happen in the Rails console, but that's not a constraint on the question. If not, is there some other way that I could find out what is currently in memory, and whether it's just a bunch of fragmented pages or if there's actually something that isn't getting garbage collected?

*EDIT*
@engineersmnky pointed out in the comments that maybe everything is fine and that perhaps Ruby is just still holding on to the OS page due to some other still-valid object therein. However, if this is the case, it strikes me as unlikely that memory usage would not go back down to the previous baseline after several days of production usage.

Loading tens of MB worth of resultset into memory should result in the allocation of >1000 16kb memory pages in just a handful of seconds. It seems reasonable to assume that the vast majority of those would contain exclusively this resultset, and could therefore be released as soon as the resultset is garbage collected.

Furthermore, I can reproduce the increased memory usage by running the same unbounded ActiveRecord query in the Rails console, and when I close that console, the memory goes down almost immediately -- exactly what I was expecting to see when the web request completes. I don't fully understand how the Rails console works when connecting to a running application, though, so this may not be relevant.

Comment: How are you certain the memory is not "garbage collected" (which is not exactly how this works). From my naive understanding of ruby's memory management, it is possible (and likely) that this memory is just simply still allocated to the ruby program (by the OS) because ruby cannot free the heap page unless the all the slots are free. This does not mean that ruby does not have free slots in which to allocate new objects it just means that the OS still sees that memory as allocated to the ruby program. I am sure someone else can come along and provide a more in depth explanation.

Comment: "It turns out that it's caused by an internal tool which was running an unbounded ActiveRecord query -- no limit and no paging" - it's like having an elephant in the room but still looking for a naughty kitten who made this mess :)

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov, my apologies. At some point while composing my question, I had written that we've added paging now, but apparently it didn't make the final edit (I'll go put it back in now). This question is not about the large amount of usage; it's about understanding why the memory is not being released afterward, and improving my understanding of the tools available to debug this sort of thing.

Comment: @engineersmnky, great point; I had not considered that Ruby was just still holding on to the OS page. However, if this is the case, it strikes me as unlikely that memory usage would not go back down to the previous baseline after several days of production usage. 

This just reinforces the need for a way to dig in and find out what's actually in there. Does Ruby offer such a thing?

Comment: "I don't fully understand how the Rails console works when connecting to a running application, though, so this may not be relevant." The console is kind of a special case compared to normal operation. You start up Rails by requiring the framework and all the rail-ties (the Rails version of package mangagement) - the "session" that you're in is actually an integration test with a faked request.

Comment: Its not actually connecting to a "real" Rails server which normally is mounted as a Rack application in a Ruby server like Puma, Unicorn or Thin and which just sits there until a HTTP request comes in and it won't actually restart for every request.

Comment: @JakeRobb unlike certain myths' claims, Ruby process in principle _can_ release memory to OS, but it happens relatively rarely and only under certain circumstances. So in reality under a normal circumstances Ruby process memory tends to grow up to a certain plateau (and rarely/slowly, but still goes down from this plateau). Also, you may found [this article](https://www.speedshop.co/2017/12/04/malloc-doubles-ruby-memory.html) interesting - not exactly what you are asking for, but still a related problem that is useful to be aware about.